# Complex integration over circle

Tags: complex-analysis

The task is to integrate
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^2-4}
$$
over circle with radius 2 and center at 1 with positive orientation.

I performed partial fractional decomposition:
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^2-4} = \int_\gamma \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{z-2}dz-\int_\gamma \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{z+2}dz
$$
And I dont know what to do next.

I had an example with
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{1}{w-a}dw 
$$
where my lecturer used parametrisation $\gamma(t) = a + re^{it}$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi]$ and did something like this:

$$
\int_\gamma \frac{1}{w-a}dw = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)-a}dt = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{re^{it}i}{a + re^{it} -a}dt = \dots
$$

In my example however, the center is at $1$ and not $2$, which makes the example useless. What can I do? In other SE questions people mentioned Cauchy integral formula, but I can't see how should I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula),
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z-a}\,dz=2\pi i$$
as soon as the circle $\gamma$, oriented counterclockwise, contains the complex point $a$ in its interior. If $a$ is outside $\gamma$ then the integral is zero by the [Cauchy Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).

Comment: This makes $\int_\gamma \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{z-2}dz = \frac{\pi i}{2}$. What about $\int_\gamma \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{z+2}dz$? $a = -2$ is not in the circle